# The closure of the elementary processes are the predictable processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am reading "Diffusion, Markov Processes and Martingales" by Roger/Williams, which state the following version of the monotone class theorem applied to bounded elementary processes $b\mathcal{E}$.

[image: Lemma 6.5 from Roger/Williams]

Later (section 27) they define the norm
[image]

and define the stochastic integral through the ito isometry. In the last step the Ito isometry should be extended from the elementary processes to as much as possible in $L^2(M)$. They just say that from Lemma 6.5 it follows that $\overline{b\mathcal{E}} = L^2(M)$.

---

In my opinion at least $(i)$ and $(ii)$ do not hold for $d[M]_s = ds$ (Brownian Motion case), since $\int_0^\infty c^2 ds = \infty$ for $c \not= 0$.

Also how come Lemma 6.5 only gives us that the bounded predictable processes are in $\mathcal{H}$ and now we just take the whole $L^2(M)$ (no boundedness assumption anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is important to notice that (not unusually) Roger and Williams have, at the point you are looking at, restricted their integrator $M$ to be a continuous $L^2$-bounded martingale. This means that at this stage, Brownian motion **is not** an allowed integrator, since it is not $L^2$-bounded. The punchline will be that by localisation, once we have the theory for $L^2$-bounded martingales, we will be able to get it for a wider class that includes Brownian motion.

This is important since it means that the class of martingales they consider satisfies $\mathbb{E}([M]_\infty) < \infty$. This will imply that constant functions are in $L^2(M)$, for example.

Now for the main body of your question. Let $U$ be the set of elementary processes in $L^2(M)$ (coinciding with the notation of Rogers/Williams). We want to show that $\overline{U} = L^2(M)$.

First we check that the space of bounded previsible process $b\mathcal{E}$ satisfies $b \mathcal{E} \subseteq \overline{U}$.

For this, we use their lemma 6.5 (the monotone class theorem). First, constant functions are in $\overline{U}$ since $c 1_{[0,n]} \to c$ in $L^2(M)$ as $n \to \infty$.

For the second condition, for arbitrary $\varepsilon$ we can pick an $N$ large enough that $|H_n(s,\omega) - H(s,\omega)| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$, $s \in (0,\infty)$ and $\omega \in \Omega$. Hence
$$\|H_n - H\|_{L^2(M)}^2 \leq \mathbb{E} \bigg [ \int_0^\infty \varepsilon d [M]_s \bigg] = \varepsilon \mathbb{E}([M]_\infty).$$ That is, the uniform convergence implies convergence in $L^2(M)$ so $H \in \overline{U}$ also since $\overline{U}$ is closed.

Finally, it is an easy exercise to use the DCT to see that $\overline{U}$ satisfies condition $3$ in Lemma 6.5 also.

Therefore, $b \mathcal{E} \subseteq \overline{U}$. You are right that general elements of $L^2(M)$ need not be bounded so we aren't quite finished. The point is that a general element of $L^2(M)$ can be approximated by functions in $b \mathcal{E}$.

The crudest way one might try to do this is to take $\phi \in L^2(M)$ and just brutally cut it off at height $N$. That is, let 
$$\phi_N = \begin{cases} N \qquad |\phi| \geq N \\
\phi \qquad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
 Then $\phi_N$ is certainly bounded and it follows by the DCT that $\phi_N \to \phi$ in $L^2(M)$. Hence $L^2(M) \subseteq \overline{b \mathcal{E}} \subseteq \overline{U}$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually they don't assume continuity yet, but I oversaw the important assumption of $L^2$ boundedness. They also alternate all the time between saying that we have $b\mathcal{E}$ and $L^2(M)$ as integrands which confuses me. Later they use $lb\mathcal{E}$ (loc, bounded elementary), instead of locally $L^2(M)$ as integrands when localizing which confuses me more. Do I understand it right, that for a $M^2_{loc}$ the integrands are "local $L^2(M)$" and for a cts local martingale (and thus $M^2_{loc}$) the integrands even include H s.t. $P[\int H_s d<M>_s < \infty] = 1$?

Comment: Usually one builds up the integral in stages and so your spaces will get bigger as you go for a fixed integrator, and then you impose extra conditions to allow you to weaken the assumption on your integrator. When you construct for $L^2$-bounded martingales, the right space is $L^2(M)$. Then you construct for local martingales and for this you only need $\mathbb{P}( \forall t, \int_0^t H_s^2 d[M]_s < \infty) = 1$. Then for semimartingales, you also need the integrand to be integrable against the finite variation part so you usually want a locally bounded, predictable integrand.